# Adding more links to the tool bar

Tags: admin-bar

I added one link to the tool bar, how can I modify the code in order to have more links?

```
function add_link_to_admin_bar($admin_bar) {
$args = array(
    'parent' => 'site-name',
'id' => 'Lignano_Sabbiadoro',
    'title' => 'Lignano Sabbiadoro', 
    'href' => '/case-vacanza/lignano-sabbiadoro-appartamenti-vacanze/',
'meta' => array(
        'target' => '_self',
    )
);
$admin_bar->add_node($args);
}   
add_action('admin_bar_menu', 'add_link_to_admin_bar', 999);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So what you need to do is repeat what you're doing, and we'll use a `foreach` loop to achieve it

I'll give you an example of code that basically does what you need, but it creates an array of arrays. You initially created `array` called `$args` which represented a single link, but you need to create an array these `$args`.

Once you create the array of `$args`, you can run over the `array` using a `foreach` and add the nodes to the menu.

```php
function add_link_to_admin_bar( $admin_bar ) {
    
    $links = [
        [
            'parent' => 'site-name',
            'id'     => 'Lignano_Sabbiadoro',
            'title'  => 'Lignano Sabbiadoro',
            'href'   => '/case-vacanza/lignano-sabbiadoro-appartamenti-vacanze/',
            'meta'   => [
                'target' => '_self',
            ]
        ],
        [
            'parent' => 'site-name',
            'id'     => 'My_Second_Link_2',
            'title'  => 'My Second Link',
            'href'   => '/case-vacanza/link-2/',
            'meta'   => [
                'target' => '_self',
            ]
        ],
        [
            'parent' => 'site-name',
            'id'     => 'My_Third_Link_3',
            'title'  => 'My Third Link',
            'href'   => '/case-vacanza/link-3/',
            'meta'   => [
                'target' => '_self',
            ]
        ],
    ];

    foreach ( $links as $link ) {
        $admin_bar->add_node( $link );
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'add_link_to_admin_bar', 999 );
```